# Cannot resolve method 'type'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to migrate to Spring Boot version 3.0.9, I get this error:

```
  @Column(name = "USER_TYPE")
  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ClassType")
  private Class<T> user;
```

I get `Cannot resolve method 'type'`

Do you know how I can replace this in version Spring Boot version 3.0.9.

Comment: Can you add the version of spring boot you are using. It manages the version of spring data jpa, not spring cloud.

Comment: Yes I use Spring Boot version `3.0.9`

Answer (score 1):

The `@Type` annotation is a Hibernate 5.x annotation, while Spring Boot 3.x upgraded to Hibernate 6.x. You should migrate the `@Type` annotation to `@Convert` to make the code work.

You might also be able to use this instead:

```
  @Type("org.hibernate.type.ClassType")
```

An example can be found here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums-custom-type

Comment: With @type annotation I get error `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends org.hibernate.usertype.UserType<?>>'`